# Smartphone controlled garage door opener

Tags: remote-control, smart-device

I am looking to replace my old, loud, and slow garage door opener. Since I have to do this soon anyway, why don't I buy one that makes my life easier.

**Requirements**

- Must be able to be controlled from a smartphone (supporting Android and iOS)
- Must remember if it is open or closed and convey that through the phone
- Must be able to lift a double wide door (current one is 1/2 HP and lifts it in ~12 seconds)
- The quieter the better

**Nice to haves**

- Quicker than current door
- Can open or close if left in half open position (at least from phone)

I have found the [LiftMaster 8550W](https://www.liftmaster.com/For-Homes/garage-door-openers/elite-series/model-8550W) that looks like it fits my requirements. Does anyone have any experience with either this opener or brand?

Comment: Can you specify the speed you're looking for? _Quicker than current door_ doesn't help much.

Comment: @Adam Above I say my current door opens in about 12 seconds. I guess somewhere around 10 seconds would be nice.

Comment: So as far as I know, remote controllers for garage doors don't include the actual motor — they're just to communicate with the motor in a different way.

Comment: @Adam I will admit that I do not know too much about garage door openers besides what they are supposed to do. If you are right about the motor, I will edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a door you could just add in a new smartphone controlled controller,
e.g. 
https://garageio.com/

Garageio is the simple and secure way to control and monitor your garage door from anywhere in the world, all without needing to replace your existing opener. The Garageio blackbox can easily be installed in your home garage, allowing control of up to three separate garage doors.

It is wifi enabled.

[image]

The one door garageio box costs $199.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the product you're recommending? What are its pros and cons, pricing, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but as I have to replace the current opener anyway, I might as well get an all-in-one solution.